# I want the first image width to be window size and others 200 dp of a grid view in android

Tags: android, image, gridview

The first image is being overlapped by the second image in the grid. I want first image to be bigger than other images.First image should match the width of the device screen.
This is my xml

```
 <GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"

    android:paddingTop="16dp"

    />
```

This is my imageadapter code

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    MainActivity mainActivity=new MainActivity();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int imgSize = 0;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        if(position!=0)
        {
            imgSize=200;
        }
        else
        {
           imgSize=size.x;
        }
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imgSize, 200));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}
```

Screen Shot of Second image overlapping the first one

[image]

Comment: try to add header in gridview rather then setting size. set first image in header and add other images in gridview

Comment: the best would be to create an Imageview above the grid. and if the position == 0 then set the image to the view.

Comment: If I give the image view separate to grid view then it won't be scrollable. I want all these scrollable. Is there any other way to do this?